# Mysql Group by column names

Tags: php, mysql

I've written a query where I select the likes and the dislikes out of a column. I get the results but now I want to add a name to each of the grouped result, is this possible ?

Table structure:

`id` ,
`snippet_id` ,
`user_id` ,
`kind`

the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(v) as likes FROM Vote v GROUP BY v.kind
```

The result I get:

array(0 => 10, 1 => 3);

I want a result like this:

array('likes' => 10, 'dislikes' => 3);

Comment: What is the table strucure? The result is from mysql or in PHP? Did you try mysql_fetch_assoc ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `v.kind` to your field list:
`SELECT v.kind, COUNT(v) as likes FROM Vote v GROUP BY v.kind`

Comment: thank you! That's the answer, going to accept you in a couple of minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you use

```
mysql_fetch_array
```

to get your results, you have to use

```
 mysql_fetch_assoc
```

I hope to help you.

Comment: Thanks but it was about the mysql itself. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. But still.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can return an associative array using [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

Comment: Thanks but it was about the mysql itself. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. But still.. Thank you!